# Is there a straightforward way to summarize an excel sheet where the rows and columns repeat?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a file where are listed parts in the first column, where those parts repeat, and in each column after that I have the locations of those parts, and those do repeat based on dates.

I need to summarize into a single sheet where rows nor columns repeat and they just "sumif" rows and columns are the same.

summarize this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

First i tried to loop through rows and columns finding duplicates and sum all together. disaster, in simple 10 x 10 table went fine but the full file has 600+ rows and 700+ columns, it looped for hours and i had to restart the PC. Currently I'm trying to use VBA to copy the selection, paste transpose in temp sheet, sort, then:

```
For i = filterLastRow To 1 Step -1

    If shtFCol.Range("B" & i) = shtFCol.Range("B" & i - 1) Then
        For j = 6 To LastCol
            shtFCol.Range("B" & i - 1) = shtFCol.Range("B" & i - 1) + shtFCol.Range("B" & i)
        Next j
        shtFCol.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i
```

Paste back to original and repeat the process to all rows. Is there a simpler / faster way?

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach.  The result is placed in a separate sheet.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, arr, r As Long, c As Long, mR, mC
    
    Set wsResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")          'sheet for result
    wsResult.Cells.ClearContents
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B4:I12") 'source data
    arr = rng.Value
    
    For r = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)        'loop input rows from row 2
        mR = Application.Match(arr(r, 1), wsResult.Columns(1), 0) 'already have row header?
        If IsError(mR) Then 'if no mtch found...
            mR = wsResult.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 'next empty cell in column A
            wsResult.Cells(mR, 1).Value = arr(r, 1)              'add the row header
        End If
        For c = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)   'loop input columns
            mC = Application.Match(arr(1, c), wsResult.Rows(1), 0) 'follow same process as for row headers
            If IsError(mC) Then
                mC = wsResult.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                wsResult.Cells(1, mC).Value = arr(1, c)
            End If
            With wsResult.Cells(mR, mC)
                .Value = .Value + 1  'increment the count for this unique pair of row/column label
            End With
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bring the range into powerquery using data ... from table/range [ ] headers

[image]

go into home ... advanced editor... and paste from below.  Use your auto generated first row in place of mine to preserve your range name

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], //use your auto generated first row in place of this one
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
Split_Dupes = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,"_"), type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Split_Dupes, List.Distinct(Split_Dupes[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

file ... close and load ... table back to excel

right click and refresh table when needed, or VBA refresh the powerquery

[image]